# Nullish coalescing assignment operator (??=) in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use the Nullish coalescing assignment operator (??=) in NodeJS, it is possible?

```js
const setValue = (object, path, value) => {
  const indices = {
      first: 0,
      second: 1
    },
    keys = path.replace(new RegExp(Object.keys(indices).join('|'), 'g'), k => indices[k]).split('.'),
    last = keys.pop();

  keys
    .reduce((o, k, i, kk) => o[k] ??= isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {}, object)[last] = value;

  return obj;
}
```

```
est.js:9
       .reduce((o, k, i, kk) => o[k] ??= isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {}, object)
                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
        at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1067:16)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1115:27)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: This means that the Node version you are running on does not yet support that operator. So *"it is possible?"*: not with that version of Node.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error means your version of Node does not yet have support for the `??=` operator.

Check out the versions which support it on [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment-----basic-support):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It's possible for node version v15.14+.

The rewrite for something like

```
a.greeting ??= "hello"
```

in node <v15.14 is:

```
a.greeting = a?.greeting ?? 'hello'
```

Maybe it does help someone :]

Answer (score 0):

The node version you are using doesn't support the nullish coalescing assignment operator.

Answer (score -1):

You could replace [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

```
o[k] ??= isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {}
```

with an assignment with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR)

```
o[k] = o[k] || (isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {})
```

Comment: `??` is not equivalent with `||`. For instance `0 ?? 1` would return 0, however `0 || 1` would return 1.

Comment: @Olian04, that comment is not relevant here, since the object `o` is completely controlled by this `reduce` call, and its properties are always objects.