# agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

So I'm learning how to make bot on discord using discord.js

this is my `bot.js`

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();
client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN_KEY);
```

this is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "aibot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./src/bot.js",
    "dev": "nodemon ./src/bot.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

So when I run `node ./src/bot.js`
I am getting this error:

```
PS E:\RIYA\AIBOT> node -v
v14.18.0

PS E:\RIYA\AIBOT> node ./src/bot.js
E:\RIYA\AIBOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\APIRequest.js:33
    agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\RIYA\AIBOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RESTManager.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

What shall I do? I don't know much about NodeJs and I'm not able to figure out how to solve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nullish coalescing assignment operator (??=) in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959998/nullish-coalescing-assignment-operator-in-nodejs)

Comment: This operator ( ??= ) was added in 2021 ( https://i.imgur.com/6XZ0jG1.png ), possibly putting the above version of the node will fix the problem

Comment: no the issue was, discord.js needs node version above 16.6 .... After I upgraded my version it started working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your **Node to version 16.6.0 or newer** to work and modify your

> 2nd and 3rd lines

of code to:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
```

To prevent

> [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS' error

Read More from the documentation
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Answer (score 6):

You have to update node.js to v16.6 or later, as per [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) (scroll down to "Installation").

Comment: thank you so much, issue is solved :)))