# error: agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });

Tags: github, heroku, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to host my Discord bot but I keep receiving this error message:

```
agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
           ^^^
 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:4:20)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "gifuploader",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/UnidentifiedGithubDeveloper/gifuploader.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/UnidentifiedGithubDeveloper/gifuploader/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/UnidentifiedGithubDeveloper/gifuploader#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.2.0"
  }
}
```

I've  already installed the latest v16 version, and ran all of the discord.js updates on my project but it still returns the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nullish coalescing assignment operator (??=) in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959998/nullish-coalescing-assignment-operator-in-nodejs)

Comment: Are you sure you're running node v16? Check by running `node -v` in the terminal

Comment: Yep, 100% running node v16.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot on Heroku throws an error: agent ??= new https.Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70443889/discord-bot-on-heroku-throws-an-error-agent-new-https-agent)