# Heroku: dbm.error: but i have a good token

Tags: node.js, heroku, token, dbm

How do l fix the error below?
I have a good token, I've changed it twice

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've changed it twice

That's a *syntax* error. The value of the token is irrelevant: the version of Node.js you're using doesn't understand [the nullish assignment operator, `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment).

It looks like support for `??=` was added to Node.js [somewhere during the v15 development cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67959998/354577). Since [Heroku supports even-numbered](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#supported-runtimes) ([long-term support](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/)) versions, you'll want to use Node.js version 16.

You can [specify the version of Node.js you wish to use via your `package.json`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version), e.g.

```json
{
  "name": "Some Application",
  "description": "An application that does cool stuff",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
}
```

Update (or set) the `node` version in your `package.json`, commit, and redeploy.