# Heroku Node.js Discord.js deployment failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, webpack

Not sure what the problem is,
Had to follow a few yt-bers one used tsc but had to switch to js completely.

```
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370270+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:33
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370282+00:00 app[worker.1]:     agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370282+00:00 app[worker.1]:           ^^^
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370283+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370283+00:00 app[worker.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370284+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370284+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370284+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370285+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370285+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370286+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370286+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370286+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:4:20)
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370287+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2022-01-09T20:58:40.370287+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2022-01-09T20:58:40.611984+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
```

The version of Node.js you are using doesn't understand [the nullish assignment operator, `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). That operator [was introduced at some point in the 15.x development cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67959998/354577).

Ask Heroku to use Node 16 (or later) by including an `engines` section in your `package.json`, e.g.

```json
{
  "name": "Some Application",
  "description": "An application that does cool stuff",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
}
```